# CKEditor alters content

Tags: ckeditor

When I save my content, it changes things that I don't want to be changed. How can I make it so it would just save my content without changing anything?

Content before saving:

`<a anything</a>`

After save, the above example becomes:

`<a a="" anything=""> </a>`

I'm trying to find a config option that would make it so when I save my content, it would save it just as it is - without adding anything of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `<a anything</a>` **is not a valid HTML** and CKEditor works only with a valid HTML. So once you try to load this content into CKEditor it (or the browser) tries to fix it.

Quoting [CKEditor basic concepts](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basics):

> CKEditor is not a tool that will let you input invalid HTML code. CKEditor abides by W3C standards so it will modify code if it is invalid.